# How to make **egg** and **patchwork** tags match?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

**egg** and **patchwork**, two packages useful for laying out and labelling figures for publication, don't actually make very similar-looking tags all the time. I happen to really like the ones made by `egg:tag_facet`, and would like to make sure my other plots have the same tags. How can I do this at a high level?

In the example below, I have fudged it so that my imaginary "figure 1" has two plots arranged with (and tagged by) **patchwork** and "figure 2" has a single, multi-panel plot that uses `ggplot2::facet_grid` and is tagged with **egg**. But the legwork here seems a bit extreme, and the `plot.tag.position` is bespoke at best, and also probably looks pretty terrible. What's the clean way to do this?

```
library(patchwork)
library(egg)
library(tidyverse)
svp <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "sepal length (mm)"
       , y = "petal length (mm)")

pps <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Species, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(x = "species"
       , y = NULL)


# imagine this was fig 1
svp +
  theme(plot.tag.position  = c(0.22, 0.97) # klugey numbers
        , text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 0.8*11)
        , axis.title = element_text(face = "plain", size = 11)
        , axis.text = element_text(face = "plain", size = 0.8*11)
  ) + 
pps + 
  theme(plot.tag.position  = c(0.15, 0.97) # klugey numbers
        , text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 0.8*11)
        , axis.title = element_text(face = "plain", size = 11)
        , legend.title = element_text(face = "plain", size = 11)
        , legend.text = element_text(face = "plain", size = 11)
        , axis.text = element_text(face = "plain", size = 0.8*11)
  ) + 
plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'a')

# and this was fig 2
slvswps <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~Species) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(1.2, "lines")
        , strip.text.x = element_text(size = rel(0.8))
        ) +
  labs(x = "sepal length (mm)", y = "sepal width (mm)")

tag_facet(slvswps, open = NULL, close = NULL)
```